# Angular 9: queryParams is adding extra characters to the route URL

Tags: angular

I have a side navigation bar in my application. All the icons in the side navigation point to different route. One of the icons should point me to a route with a query param. Example- `localhost:4200/test?t=1`.

I have an interface for my navigation items that looks like this.

```
export interface NavigationItem {
  link: string;
  parameters?: string;
  icon: string;
}
```

I have an array of these Navigation items that I loop over on my side navigation bar.
One of the items in the array is this-

```
{
    link: 'test',
    parameters: '{t:1}',
    icon: 'newIcon',
  }
```

This is the code snippet in my `*ngFor`

```
<a [routerLink]="[item.link]" [queryParams]="item.parameters" routerLinkActive="active" class="navigation-item">
  <mat-icon matListIcon class="icon">{{ item.icon }}</mat-icon>
</a>
```

I was expecting the route `localhost:4200/test?t=1` to open on the icon click. But the route that's being formed is `localhost:4200/test?0=%7B&1=t&2=:&3=1&4=%7D`

Can you tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `parameters` field on `NavigationItem` is a string so Angular is URL encoding it.

You can either convert parameters to be of type `Params` (which I strongly recommend) or convert the string to an object using `JSON.parse(item.parameters)`

Your object should look like:

```js
export interface NavigationItem {
  link: string;
  parameters?: Params;
  icon: string;
}
```

And you can create it as:

```js
const item = {
  link: 'test',
  parameters: {
    t: 1
  },
  icon: 'newIcon',
} as NavigationItem
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters should be of type [`Params`](https://angular.io/api/router/Params), otherwise it encodes the string you pass in to be usable as a URL

```
export interface NavigationItem {
  link: string;
  parameters?: Params;
  icon: string;
}

const item = {
  link: 'test',
  parameters: { t: 1 },
  icon: 'newIcon',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to assign type Params to your `parameters` in interface

```
import { Params } from '@angular/router';

export interface NavigationItem {
  link: string;
   parameters?: Params;
   icon: string;
}
```

Angular now consider parameters as router params hence avoid encoding it.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to provide the parameters is using a [Params](https://angular.io/api/router/Params) type because of the [queryParams](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#queryParams) doesn't accept a string value. Check your example with the solution from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bwhtsh?file=src/app/app.component.html).